# How many $3 \times 2$ grids in the $5 \times 5$ grid?

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a formula to evaluate the number of all rectangles in the $m \times n\; (5\cdot5)$ grid, without overlap? That rectangles should be in $a \times b\; (3\cdot2)$. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, if $a>m$ or $b>n$ this number is $0$.

Otherwise, just count the number of possible placements of the "lower left" corner of the $a \times b$-grid within the $m \times n$-grid.

(as often in counting problems, "just" find an intuitive representation of all solutions to the problem that allows for a comfortable counting)

This insight directly leads to the fact that we can place the lower left corner of the smaller grid at $m-a+1$ positions "horizontally" and $n-b+1$ positions "vertically", and we already considered all possible placements.

Thus, overall there are $(m-a+1) \cdot (n-b+1)$ such placements.

Comment: Thanks this formula working fine. is it possible to find matrix values also ?

Comment: What is the formula for same without overlapping each other ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of all rectangles without overlap"? Do you want to put multiple small grids within the large grid?

Comment: Yes i want to arrange two small grids within the large grid.in different possible ways.how to find possible ways ?